# Export Tasks folder to new PST file?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I need to export the Tasks folder of an Outlook 2007 PST file.

The File > Export section only supports "Export RSS Feeds to an OPML File" or "Export to a file", the latter being just a comma- or tab-separatated file.

Is there a way to export the Tasks section to a new PST file instead ?

Thank you.

---

Edit: Found it.

1. Create a new Outlook file through File > New > Outlook Data File
2. In the old file, right-click on the folder you wish to copy
3. Select "Copy "My Folder""
4. Select the new file, where the folder will be copied.

[image]

Comment: I tried a few things with Outlook 2007 to test this and I keep getting errors so . . . I'm stumped but I tried.

Comment: You mean MS didn't consider it important that users could copy folders from one PST file to another ?

Comment: I'm not sure honestly, I just tried it and ran into error messages when the operation went to complete. I had an old Win 7 machine with Outlook 2007 that I connected to and tried a few things and it gave errors. It could be the machine perhaps but don't have any other Outlook 2007 machines to test from so I was just giving you my result upon testing only in case you hear similar from others then it may not be possible or a limitation with that version of Outlook and what you are trying to do—I'm not sure but those were my results.

Comment: Tried copy/pasting between the current PST file into a new PST file: Nothing happened, file empty.